# Permutation matrices that commute

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, permutation-matrices

Just simple question:

Can anyone provide a list of types of permutation matrices that commute (with the matrices of the same type)?

for one, I can think of rotation matrix... (Oh, wait. it isn't really permutation matrix..)

Comment: Not sure what you exactly mean by *the same type*. But it is easy to see that permutation matrices commute if and only if the corresponding permutations commute. So you can ask an equivalent question: When do permutations commute?

Comment: Are you asking about commutative subgroups of the group of all permutation matrices of a given size (equivalently of the corresponding symmetric group)? That would be very hard to do exhaustively, given that any finite (abelian) group can be embdded in a symmetric group, in many ways.

Comment: E.g. you might look at [this posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/233423/permutation-matrices-that-commute).

Answer (score 3):

Conjugation of one permutation by another leaves the cycle structure unchanged, but permutes the letters in the cycles according to the second permutation.  So a permutation $\sigma$ that commutes with $\pi$ must map each cycle of $\pi$ to a cycle of $\pi$ (with the same length, of course).  For example, the permutations of $6$ letters that commute with $(123)(456)$ will either map $(123)$ and $(456)$ to themselves or interchange them.  They are determined by what they do to $1$ and $4$.  Thus there are $6 \times 3 = 18$ possibilities, including
the identity (maps $1 \to 1$ and $4 \to 4$) and $(162435)$ (maps $1 \to 6$ and $4 \to 3$).

Answer (score 2):

In general, if a permutation $\sigma$ has a disjoint cycle decomposition with $n_{i}$ $i$-cycles for each $i$, then $C_{S_{n}}(\sigma) $ has the structure $\prod_{i} (C_{i} \wr S_{n_{i}}$, where $C_{i}$ is the cyclic group of order $i$ generated by one of the $i$-cycles of $\sigma$(viewed as an element of $S_{i}$). The wreath product $\wr$ is a standard group theoretic construction, and $|C_{i} \wr S_{n_{i}}|= i^{n_{i}} (n_{i})!.$